# pivot calculator problem getting it too work, something is wrong with the variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a pivot calculator to calculate future forex and stock prices, part of a strategy from Mark Fisher's the logical trader. I have tried a couple of ways to make this calculator. Let me know how I can fix this code to make it work. Thank you in advance. How can I debug?

```js
function calculatePivot() {
  var high = document.getElementById("high").value;

  var low = document.getElementById("low").value;

  var close = document.getElementById("close").value;

  var dailyPivot = document.getElementById("high").value + document.getElementById("low").value + document.getElementById("close").value;

  var preSecondNumber = document.getElementById("high").value + document.getElementById("close").value;

  var secondNumber = document.getElementById("preSecondNumber").value / 2;

  var pivotdifferential = document.getElementById("dailyPivot").value - document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

  var pivotrange1 = document.getElementById("dailyPivot").value + document.getElementById("pivotdifferential").value;

  var pivotrange2 = document.getElementById("dailyPivot").value - document.getElementById("pivotdifferential").value;

  alert(parseInt(dailyPivot) + parseInt(pivotdifferential));
  alert(parseInt(dailyPivot) - parseInt(pivotdifferential));
  console.log(document.getElementById("high").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="high">
<input type="text" name="" id="low">
<input type="text" name="" id="close">
<button onclick="calculatePivot()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.getElementById("x")` return string value.You should parse string to number with `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()` or `Number()`:

```
function calculatePivot() {
  var high = Number(document.getElementById("high").value);

  var low = Number(document.getElementById("low").value);

  var close = Number(document.getElementById("close").value); 

  var dailyPivot = high + low + close;

  var preSecondNumber = high + close;

  var secondNumber = preSecondNumber / 2;

  var pivotdifferential = dailyPivot - secondNumber;

  var pivotrange1 = dailyPivot + pivotdifferential;

  var pivotrange2 = dailyPivot- pivotdifferential;

  alert(dailyPivot+pivotdifferential);
  alert(dailyPivot-pivotdifferential);
}
```

Comment: Hey my friend thanks for responding. It works but it is not calculating probably. Do I need to debug to find the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was edited my ans. Hope this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing your function by this function, I this problem is with `parseInt()`, need to call when take values from ,

```
function calculatePivot() {
  var high = parseInt(document.getElementById("high").value);

  var low = parseInt(document.getElementById("low").value);

  var close = parseInt(document.getElementById("close").value);

  var dailyPivot = high + low + close;

  var preSecondNumber = high + close;

  var secondNumber = preSecondNumber / 2;

  var pivotdifferential = dailyPivot - secondNumber;

  var pivotrange1 = dailyPivot + pivotdifferential;

  var pivotrange2 = dailyPivot- pivotdifferential;

  alert(dailyPivot + pivotdifferential);
  alert(dailyPivot - pivotdifferential);
  console.log(high);
}
```